# I have 2 tables and am trying to select at random a value that does not exist in the other table but I cant get it to work

Tags: mysql

[ANSWERED TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7bZZ.png)

The following is a questions table. I am trying to select at random a question that has not already been answered and so does not exist in the `answered_questions` table. The following query includes values that already exist in `questions_answered`

[QUESTIONS TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJlw.png)

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category = 'Random' and question NOT EXISTS (SELECT question FROM answered_questions WHERE game_id=6 and answered_questions.question = questions.question)ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exists donesn't compare with any field

you may use WHERE NOT EXISTS (Subquery)

That will be true if subquery has 0 rows or false if it has 1 or more rows.

You can also use IN like WHERE question in (SELECT question from answers...)

That is true if the subquery returns the same question.